# name space highlighting is not working in visual studio when using modules declaration instead of headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module, namespaces, c++20

i'm working on C++20 standard but a weird scenario happens when I started using
import statement instead of #include suddenly namespace highlighting is not working properly.

working:
[image: working highlight]

not working:
[image: not working highlight]

I don't know what is going on here I suspect it highlights according to a different thing now

Comment: Please don't paste code as image. Copy and paste the code in the post itself.

Comment: @kiner_shah the relevant fact here is *how* his IDE is highlighting the code; that cannot be conveyed by a code-only/text-only post.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a bug of Visual Studio. When using import, the intellisense will not work. You could report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62&q=module++intellisense). [Related issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-not-working-with-module-hea/1446480?space=62&q=module++intellisense) have also been reported.